# Smallest possible value on Fibonacci Function

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Suppose $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, such that for all non-negative integers $n$ the $n$-th Fibonacci number $u_n$ divides $f(u_{n+1})$. Find the smallest possible positive value of $f(4)$.

Comment: This is a current problem at brilliant.org: http://brilliant.org/i/C4F9a6/. Moderators, please note.

Comment: The above question is posted as a Challenge problem on Brilliant.org, which offers weekly problem sets to test student's problem solving abilities. John Chang has been posting questions on math.stackexchange.com and expecting others to solve the problems for him. He has posted another one of our questions at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238677/determining-the-number-n -Calvin Lin Mathematics Challenge Master

Answer (score 7):

This is a really nice problem!  The answer is $255$.  First note that (by taking integer linear combinations of polynomials with the given property) the problem is equivalent to "find the GCD of all possible nonzero values of $f(4)$".  Now observe that $g(x)=x^4-1$ is one such polynomial (left as an exercise! see hint below), and $g(4)=255$.  So the answer is some divisor of $255 = 3 \times 5 \times 17$.

To conclude, we need to show that $f(4)$ must always be divisible by $3$, by $5$, and by $17$.

But $21 \mid f(34)$, so $f(34)$ is divisible by $3$; and $f(34) \equiv f(4) \pmod{3}$ (because $34-4$ is divisible by $3$), so $f(4)$ is also divisible by $3$.

Similarly $34 \mid f(55)$, so $f(55)$ is divisible by $17$; and $f(55) \equiv f(4) \pmod{17}$ (because $55-4$ is divisible by $17$), so $f(4)$ is also divisible by $17$.

Finally $55 \mid f(89)$, so $f(89)$ is divisible by $5$; and $f(89) \equiv f(4) \pmod{5}$ (because $89-4$ is divisible by $5$), so $f(4)$ is also divisible by $5$.  Done.